# Clarity Spinner Button is there a workaround to prevent transition back to Default State from Success State?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Looking for an implementation which maintains the state as success and doesn't transition , if this is not the right forum please do direct me to one where I could find help.
// html code

```
<button [clrLoading]="validateBtnState" class="btn btn-info-outline" (click)="validateDemo()">Validate</button>
<button [clrLoading]="validateBtnState" class="btn btn-info-outline" (click)="validateDemo()">Validate</button>
```

// ts code

```
import { ClrLoadingState } from '@clr/angular';

export class ButtonLoadingDemo {
  validateBtnState: ClrLoadingState = ClrLoadingState.DEFAULT;
  submitBtnState: ClrLoadingState = ClrLoadingState.DEFAULT;

  validateDemo() {
    this.validateBtnState = ClrLoadingState.LOADING;
    //Validating Logic
    this.validateBtnState = ClrLoadingState.SUCCESS;
  }

  submitDemo() {
    this.submitBtnState = ClrLoadingState.LOADING;
    //Submit Logic
    this.submitBtnState = ClrLoadingState.DEFAULT;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can accomplish this using css and setting the disabled attribute on the button to true.

Comment: @nullptr.t Do you have a stack blitz of this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible, the logic to go from SUCCESS->DEFAULT is internalized and not configurable. If you have a use case, this is something to request through https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues.